# HTML Tooltip not showing in CEFsharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a chromium embedded framework c# in a Winforms application that does not have Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls. I don't have app.manifest too. when I open a webpage containing tooltips (HTML title attribute) using the chromium browser, these tooltips are not shown.

Is this a bug? Is it possible to see these tooltips?

Comment: It's a requirement imposed upon us by Chromium,  it is not a bug. I'm not aware of a method of displaying tooltips without Common Controls. You can ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php for a second opinion.

Comment: You can try using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex to load only ICC_BAR_CLASSES perhaps you can come to a compromise with your architect.

Comment: I have answered an almost identical question at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2854#issuecomment-516779066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case, we need to **generate an app.manifest** for the project. The way:

In Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 you can add the manifest file to your project. **Right-click** your project file on the **Solution Explorer**, **select Add**, then **New item** (or CTRL+SHIFT+A). There you can find **Application Manifest File**. 
The file name is app.manifest.

after app.manifest is generated **uncomment** this part:

```
 <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity
              type="win32"
              name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
              version="6.0.0.0"
              processorArchitecture="*"
              publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
              language="*"
            />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

once done, build the project, you can see the HTML tooltips in your chromium embedded framework c# in a Winforms application.

I hope if anyone gets this issue, this can help them.